# Multiple instances of usercontrol on one page but only the last control is being referenced

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a `UserControl` that allows the user to upload files and also displays them in a `GridView`.  On the parent page, I have a jQuery tab control to which I dynamically add 2 instances of my `UserControl` (on different tabs).  The second instance works fine, so I know the control works.  However, when I try to upload a file using the first instance, the second instance is being referenced...so all property values, control names, etc are pointing that that of the second.

This is how I am loading the controls in the parent page code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MyControl ucAttachments1 = (MyControl) Page.LoadControl("~/controls/mycontrol.ascx");
  ucAttachments1.ID = "ucAttachments1";
  ucAttachments1.Directory = "/uploads/documents";
  ucAttachments1.DataChanged += new MyControl.DataChangedEventHandler(DoSomething);
  phAttachments1.Controls.Add(ucAttachments1);

  MyControl ucAttachments2 = (MyControl)Page.LoadControl("~/controls/mycontrol.ascx");
  ucAttachments2.ID = "ucAttachments2";
  ucAttachments2.Directory = "/uploads/drawings";
  ucAttachments2.DataChanged += new MyControl.DataChangedEventHandler(DoSomething);
  phAttachmetns2.Controls.Add(ucAttachments2);
}
```

in the html:

```
<div id="tabContainer">
    <div id="files">
        <asp:PlaceHolder id="phAttachments1" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div id="drawings">
        <asp:PlaceHolder id="phAttachments2" runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>
```

a snippet of the user control code:

```
private string directory;

override protected void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    PopulateAttachmentGridview();
}

protected btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UploadFile(directory);
}

public string Directory
{
    get { return directory; }
    set { directory = value; }
}
```

How can I ensure my usercontrols are being referenced correctly?

Comment: I think we need to see more code

Comment: What is the code in DoSomething method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the actual html and javascript rendered to the client to ensure that there isn't a duplicate ID related to the controls slipping through the cracks.

Comment: I had previously checked all control ids to ensure no dups, but not the javascript.  The problem was that I had duplicate javascript code and the correct dialog wasn't coming up and thus, triggering the wrong button. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the problem

```
MyControl ucAttachments1 = (MyControl) Page.LoadControl("~/controls/mycontrol.ascx");

MyControl ucAttachments2 = (MyControl)Page.LoadControl("~/controls/mycontrol.ascx");
```

you are referencing the same instance of the control to two different variables. So now you have two different references of the same instance, Now since you set the properties for "ucAttachments2" at last so whats happening is your second control properties are being set on to the instance.. thus whenever you try to access that instance(by using "ucAttachments1" or "ucAttachments2" ) you are getting the properties of second control.

TRY DOING :

```
MyControl ucAttachments1 = new MyControl();
ucAttachments1 = (MyControl) Page.LoadControl("~/controls/mycontrol.ascx");
 ucAttachments1.ID = "ucAttachments1";
  ucAttachments1.Directory = "/uploads/documents";
  ucAttachments1.DataChanged += new MyControl.DataChangedEventHandler(DoSomething);
  phAttachments1.Controls.Add(ucAttachments1);


MyControl ucAttachments2 = new MyControl();
ucAttachments2 = (MyControl) Page.LoadControl("~/controls/mycontrol.ascx");
ucAttachments2.ID = "ucAttachments2";
  ucAttachments2.Directory = "/uploads/drawings";
  ucAttachments2.DataChanged += new MyControl.DataChangedEventHandler(DoSomething);
  phAttachmetns2.Controls.Add(ucAttachments2);
```